# RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding Decryption on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cryptography, rsa

I have searched alot regarding my task which is like ,

i am getting data through XML which is encrypted using **RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding** from backend and they have given me a file name **"publickey.der"**. According to them this is public key and you need to use this key for decryption.

Seriously i dont have any idea about using this public key for decryption on Objective C.

Please guide me which framework or library or sdk i need to use or any one has any sample code for this. I am counting on you guys only.

Looking forward for your responses

Thank you once again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding. ECB is a mode of operation for a block cipher (e.g AES) not a public key scheme (e.g RSA). Anyway it might be worth looking at the [CommonCrypto Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html)

Comment: @NathanBaggs `"ECB"` is often used as a synonym for `"None"` in Java for RSA. Basically you can encrypt in ECB mode by splitting up the plaintext as blocks 11 bytes smaller than the key size, then encrypt each block. This is identical to the way AES is performed in ECB mode. Of course it is extremely slow, you have lots of overhead, but it can be done. In this case though I presume `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` is simply used as input for the XML encryption API that is in Java.

Comment: Could you please indicate what container format is used for the encrypted data? Is XML encryption used? If you don't know, please post some encrypted test data.

Answer (score 2):

[Public keys are used for encryption, private keys are used for decryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#How_it_works). You will have to rectify this issue first.

Also RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding is not common, when you want to rsa encrypt a large amount of data, usually you encrypt an aes key with rsa and encrypt your data with aes instead.

Basically, to do this RSA/ECB decrypt outside of java, it will be manually, and you are going to have to break your cipher text up by your block size (key size), and then decrypt each block without padding, until the final block with padding, that's how you get the ECB.

This is not ideal, that combined with them providing you with a public key and telling you to decrypt, suggests that whoever is giving you the data needs to fix their encryption issues.